# XNA showing blank window, no matter what i write in the editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I just installed visual studio c# express and I an able to write console application in c# with desired output.

But, when i installed XNA 4.0 and started a project for windows game, no matter what i write in the editor, it doesn't show any output.

the editor shows only some syntax errors and

even if i write-
hello;
it doesn't show any error;
the editor doesn't match parenthesis and it shows all colors in black irrespective of whether it is a class or a function or whatever.

it seems like a problem with the editor or xna.
it was working for console app but for windows game it shows just the blank blue screen of xna output, no matter what i write in the editor.

what to do?

Comment: Sounds to me like a problem with the editor. Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? If the problem persists, try resetting your Visual Studio settings.

Comment: The problem was in that project.
I started a new windows game project and that is working.

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please show us the code and error messages you are getting? It will help us find a solution to your problem.